# S3Cmd fails as www-data and works as root

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-s3, s3cmd

I am running `s3cmd` on Ubuntu as root and it works fine, no issues. But as www-data which is the user my cron uses it fails and I get this.

> /var/backups/archives/files/file_name_27-01-2013_01:00:27.tar.gz -> s3://yolkmesh/london/archives/files/file_name_27-01-2013_01:00:27.tar.gz
>   [1 of 69]  57344 of 73404    78% in    1s    31.58 kB/s  failed
>   WARNING: Upload failed:
>   /london/archives/files/file_name_27-01-2013_01:00:27.tar.gz
>   ([Errno 32] Broken pipe) WARNING: Retrying on lower speed
>   (throttle=0.00) WARNING: Waiting 3 sec...

This keeps failing with longer and longer waiting periods. Why is this occurring for one user and not another.

If there is no fix can I run the following as root from my cron script?

```
s3cmd put --recursive /var/backups/archives/ s3://yolkmesh/london/archives/
```

`s3cmd` is up to date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its possible that s3cmd isn't configured for the second user. Do you have a .s3cfg file for www-data? If not, run s3cmd --configure as that user to allow s3cmd to work.

Comment: It was this. Although I'd already worked it out. Just glad someone else posted an answer before I wrote my own! The error is really misleading and no help at all!

Comment: Indeed, s3cmd error messages are not that helpful. :/ But it does its job, and there's no alternative in sight, so I remain a happy user...

Comment: Question, can I just copy-paste `.s3cfg` from one user to the other, or is there  something else?

Comment: You should be able to copy the .s3cfg file from one user to another without an issue. I'm not sure if the user details are stored in that file, but I recommend you check - you can open it up in vi or any text editor.